# What is the probability of finding a number of the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$ in $\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348584/what-is-the-probability-of-finding-a-number-of-the-form-fracnn1-between), I want to ask:

> Suppose $q$ is drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$. What is the probability that the reduced form of $q$ has the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$ conditioned on $q\in\Bbb{Q}$?

(I'm reminded that one can't have a probability distribution on a countably infinite discrete set; but I don't recall offhand how to prove that there are no Borel probability measures on *any* countably infinite set. So I think the modification above will make sense but am happy to contemplate reasons why it doesn't and/or alternative probability measures to use on $\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.)

Here's my quick answer attempt. It will become evident that it's flawed but I don't have clarity on how exactly to fix the argument -- mostly I don't have good intuition for the function 
$$n\mapsto \#\{\mbox{integers $k<n$ that are coprime to $n$}\}.$$

I'm going to write
$$ \Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1] = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty Q_n $$
where
$$ Q_n =  \bigg\{ \frac{k}{n+1}\ \bigg|\ k=0,1,\ldots,n+1 \bigg\}.$$
For each $n$ we have $|Q_n| = n+1$. As there is precisely one element of $Q_n$ of the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$ we have for each $N$ the probability of randomly drawing such an element from $\cup_{n=0}^N Q_n$ is no less than
$$ \frac{N+1}{\sum_{j=0}^N Q_j} = \frac{N+1}{1+2+\cdots + N+1} = \frac{2(N+1)}{(N+1)(N+2)} = \frac{2}{N+2} $$
However: This goes to zero, so: great, the probability is no less than zero

Notice that for composite $n$, many elements of $Q_n$ are not in reduced form, so I'm overcounting a *lot* of fractions.

> Am I overcounting enough fractions to push the probability that $q = \frac{n}{n+1}$ above zero?

Comment: You can't have a uniform probability distribution on a countably infinite set.

Comment: @paw88789 Good call! Then I'll modify the question.

Comment: The probability is zero.  Consider how many numbers are of the form $\frac nk$ with $k>n+1$.

Comment: I'd say it is "not even zero"

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't think we know that without a distribution.  There are countably infinite rationals of the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and countably many not of this form.  So the two sets are equinumerous; so perhaps the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @paw88789 Sorry, I meant the density is zero.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $ 0 > Pr[q=n/(n+1)] > -\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$? :P

Comment: It seems to me that if we had a distribution for the numerator and for the denominator separately and independently, then we'd have a positive probability for our answer.  But perhaps this is reading too much into the question.

Comment: @paw88789 Also, your suggestion that the probability would be $\frac12$ has false logic.  While it is true that the cardinality of the naturals and the rationals are equal, the rationals have a' higher probability' of being picked than the naturals.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I wasn't seriously proposing that the 'correct' answer is $\frac12$.  :-)

Comment: @paw88789 I'm definitely open to revising the question further.

Comment: This kind of questions do make sense. The probability of taking two integers randomly which are coprime is known, so why not?
Actually I just made an experiment and got $\frac{91}{10000}$ consecutive pairs of random numbers. To be fair I restricted the range to $10^6$. Increasing the range to $10^8$ I got only one on $10,000$
I just realized that the experiment is not right. I considered only the irreducible fractions. I am going to redo it properly

Comment: Can you condition on a null event?

Comment: As has been said in the comments above : there is no uniform probability on a countable set. Therefore the answer will completely depend on the probability measure. It could be any $x\in [0;1]$, depending on the measure you're willing to put. According to the measurable sets you allow, it is possibly not defined. So the answer is "as you wish"

Comment: One might note that $\frac n{n+1}=1-\frac1{n+1}$, so it comes down to "what's the probability that I happen to choose a number of the form $\frac1n$".

Comment: @Ranc Why not? c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110112/probability-conditional-on-a-zero-probability-event

Comment: @Neal  From the link: You can "condition on an individual event of probability zero, if that event admits a natural approximation by events of positive probability".  I don't see how that applies here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the conditioning solves the problem of defining a uniform probability measure over the rationals.

If, for$X\sim U[0,1]$, we were allowed to condition on the (zero probability) event $A \equiv X \in \mathbb{Q}$ ([I don't think we can](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110112/probability-conditional-on-a-zero-probability-event)) then, for any $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ we'd should be able to calculate $P(X=q \mid A)=\alpha$ ; but again, this cannot work, because of additivity: no value of $\alpha$ can give us $\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} P(X=q \mid A) =1$

We'd need some non-uniform (and not simple) measure, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000359/constructing-a-measure-on-the-rational-numbers/1000369#1000369).

So, I'm afraid it's hard to make sense of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For every $n$ such that

$$x_n=\frac n{n+1}$$

There exists **infinitely many** rationals of the form

$$y_n=\frac nk,k>n+1$$

Thus, the 'probability' of choosing a number of the form $x_n$ is $0$.

---

Note a probability of $0$ does not mean it is impossible for you to choose a number of the form of $x_n$, but rather that it is improbable.

[A classic example is the probability you'd choose $1$ out of all the real numbers in $[0,1]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964057/zero-probability)

Comment: Sorry to be dense - does this imply an answer to my revised question, conditioning $q = \frac{n}{n+1}$ on $q\in\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Neal I'm unsure what you mean.  Are you taking $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus-1$?  Either way, yes, the density of your $q$ is zero in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Let $R = \{\frac{n}{n+1}\ |\ n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ and $Q = \Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. My revised question is: what is $\operatorname{Pr}[R|Q]$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Pretty sure it's still zero.

Comment: Does this mean that the probability of each one specific rational is $0$? Because if so, then this is not a (conditional) probability distribution. (The (conditional) probabilities don't sum to $1$.)

Comment: @paw88789 Indeed, that is the case.  It's like the probability of choosing 1 out of all the natural numbers, to give an analogy.

Comment: When you say "*the* probability of choosing 1 out of all the natural numbers," what do you mean?

Comment: @CameronBuie something along the lines of density, like how the even numbers and off numbers have 1/2 density in the natural and the primes have 0 density in the naturals.